# Making a solr type search engine using derby and redis

Tags: java, rest, solr, redis, derby

**I am currently making a web project for searching**

I will search through a database of about 1000 pages or more.
The search would be an optimizer search i.e. user will get autocomplete suggestions from previously searched queries using redis and i will use derby database.

The whole idea is that i have a page that sends request to a rest api which has info on the searched query from the derby database and i will use the EHCache or redis to further optimize the result.

I've built the web page with a servlet which handles the query and also a servletDB handling the db connection.

The problem is that I dont know how to go about with the idea.
I want to know how do i start with the idea. Any help help or source material will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This seems like total overkill for 1000 pages unless the pages are gigantic.

Comment: I currently have no idea about the page length or the number of pages. I just gave rough estimate. This is a project given to me.

Comment: Knowing the scale at which you are trying to solve the problem is hugely important. There is a really big difference between building a personal website and a large scale website, it’s the difference between 1 engineer spending a few days and 100’s of engineers spending years.

Comment: I have made a derby database and the homepage for the search, now i wanted to know how to make a restful api from the combination of derby db i made, redix and solr so that I can search through the database I made and can optimize with caching and query suggestion.

Comment: I know i am being very vague and passing incomplete info but this is my first time working on these technologies and would really appreciate your input for the same.